# connecting custom List view with a simple screen

Tags: android

I developing an application where there is custom List view and a simple screen.
How can I connect both these screen. for an eg If I click in Health care goals the Second Screen(i.e App2Activity)  should come.

The code for main page is as follows:

```
package com.androidexample.customlistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;


public class CustomListViewAndroidExample extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    public  CustomListViewAndroidExample CustomListView = null;
    public  ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list_view_android_example);

        CustomListView = this;

        /******** Take some data in Arraylist ( CustomListViewValuesArr ) ***********/
        setListData();

        Resources res =getResources(); 
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        /**************** Create Custom Adapter *********/
        adapter=new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArr,res);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    /****** Function to set data in ArrayList *************/
    public void setListData()
    {

        final ListModel sched = new ListModel();
         sched.setCompanyName("HealthCareTeam");
         sched.setImage("image"+0);
         CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);

         final ListModel sched1 = new ListModel();
         sched1.setCompanyName("HealthCareGoals");
         sched1.setImage("image"+1);
         CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched1);

         final ListModel sched2= new ListModel();
         sched2.setCompanyName("TestResults");
         sched2.setImage("image"+2);
         CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched2);

         final ListModel sched3= new ListModel();
         sched3.setCompanyName("Medication");
         sched3.setImage("image"+3);
         CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched3);

         final ListModel sched4= new ListModel();
         sched4.setCompanyName("Exercise");
         sched4.setImage("image"+4);
         CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched4);

         final ListModel sched5 = new ListModel();
         sched5.setCompanyName("Diet");
         sched5.setImage("image"+5);
         CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched5);

         final ListModel sched6= new ListModel();
         sched6.setCompanyName("FindHospitals");
         sched6.setImage("image"+6);
         CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched6);

         final ListModel sched7= new ListModel();
         sched7.setCompanyName("Settings");
         sched7.setImage("image"+7);
         CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched7);



    }

    public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
    {
        ListModel tempValues = (ListModel) CustomListViewValuesArr.get(mPosition);

        Toast.makeText(CustomListView, 
                ""+tempValues.getCompanyName()+" \nImage:"+tempValues.getImage(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
    }


}
```

code for screen 2 is as follows:

package com.example.myandroidapp1;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class App2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app2);

    }

}
```

How can I connect both these Pages.Please Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use like this

MaainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private EditText et;
ListView list;
String[] web = {
        "A",
        "G",
        "Gt",
        "L",
        "H",
        "Ln",
        "Hli",
        "Hi",
        "Ht",
        "Jo",
        "Gan"


} ;

Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs,
        R.drawable.imagecxvs


};
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                      list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Good_mornig.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 1 :
                    Intent ge = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Good_evening.class);
                    startActivity(ge);
                    break;
                    case 2 :
                        Intent gn = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Good_night.class);
                        startActivity(gn);
                        break;
                    case 3 :
                        Intent lv = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Love_sms.class);
                        startActivity(lv);
                        break;
                    case 4 :
                        Intent ht = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Hate_sms.class);
                        startActivity(ht);
                        break;
                    case 5 :
                        Intent lvp = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Lovely_person.class);
                        startActivity(lvp);
                        break;
                    case 6 :
                        Intent hdiwali = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Happy_diwali.class);
                        startActivity(hdiwali);
                        break;
                    case 7 :
                        Intent hdlti = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Happy_dhuleti.class);
                        startActivity(hdlti);
                        break;
                    case 8 :
                        Intent hj = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Happy_janmastmi.class);
                        startActivity(hj);
                        break;
                    case 9 :
                        Intent jokes = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Jokes.class);
                        startActivity(jokes);
                        break;  
                    case 10 :
                        Intent gc = new Intent (MainActivity.this , Ganeshchturthi.class);
                        startActivity(gc);
                        break;  


                    }
                  //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                };



            });
}
}
```

Adapter (CustomeList)

```
 public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

 private final Activity context;
 private final String[] web;
 private final Integer[] imageId;
 public CustomList(Activity context,
 String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
 super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
 this.context = context;
this.web = web;
this.imageId = imageId;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
return rowView;
}
 }
```

Comment: hi...the code which you have given is now working.Now the List is Displying.But its not navigating to Good_morning.class.

Comment: do I need to include anything in manifest file in order to start the  second activity

Comment: yes....   when u create a new class then its necessary to define that class in manifest file..

Comment: I have one more question..how can I increase the length of each list item as the items are coming in very congested form.Please suggest

Comment: android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: hi...I am facing one more issue.suppose there is a list(eg.List1).When I am clicking on one of the item present in list1 it displays list2.Again when I am clicking any Item Present in list2,list3 should be displayed.How can I do that.Even though I have mentioned all the activities in manifest file its not coming.

Comment: hi I have tried android:layout_width="fill_parent" then also the list is coming in congested form.How can I change that.

Comment: u need to use divider

Comment: Is there any other way.Its still coming like that.

Comment: yes.... if u want then u can use edittext and put your message in edittext....   u can use your list of edittext in scrollview , so its look like a listview

Comment: hi bhavya I am trying to include a paragragh in my android project.can You please help me what I need to do.I have posted one query in stack overflow.Plese look over it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197866/how-to-write-a-paragraph-in-android

Comment: you can write your paragraph directly in xml file...  like  android:text = "this is first line,                                   this is second line                                                   this is third line";    i think this help for u try it..

Comment: Thanks Bhayani for your earlier Posts.It has really helped me a lot. I have certain queries regarding the creation of charts in android.Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236724/creation-on-charts-in-android.Please Help

Answer (score 1):

u can use like this for go to second activity.... or every list item click and open different activity as your need.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
          switch(position){
          case 0:
              Intent firstIntent = new Intent(yorclass.this, App2Activity.class);
              startActivity(firstIntent);
              break;  
          case 1:
              Intent secondintent = new Intent(yourclass.this, App3Activity.class);
              startActivity(secondintent);
              break;
```

Comment: hi  I have tried to implement Your logic..but still its not working.The list is only not displayed.

Comment: The code is as follows: `list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                         adapter=new CustomAdapter(CustomListView,                             CustomListViewValuesArr,res);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                   int position, long id)
          {
                     Intent firstIntent = new Intent(CustomListViewAndroidExample.this, App2Activity.class);
                     startActivity(firstIntent);
  
          }});
 }`

Comment: hii I have tried your logic.But its not working.Can you Please tell me where should i include this snippet.when i m trying to include it after this 'list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);' The List is not displayed.Please Help.

Comment: in this code... where u use switch statment .. use switch statment and then try again.

Comment: i'll post my code... u can use same like for ur need

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to navigate to another activity. Read given documents for the detailed info and usage. Even you can find more code and details on [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) document.

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(activityone.this, activitytwo.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent is the way to go. Use the following code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(CustomListViewAndroidExample.this, App2Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example code on how to use viewPager and Fragments.

Then afterwards, you can feel more comfort to use fragments, they are more flexible,yet fragile. (IMO, Handle with care)

> > https://github.com/ProMobile/ViewPagerTutorial

Answer (score 0):

context.startActivity(context, App2Activity.class);