# How to write a paragraph in android

Tags: android

I am trying to insert a paragraph in android application.
My code is like this:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        t.setText("This is the first line\nThis is the second line\nThird line...");
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld_5.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
    <TextView
        android:text="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunately The app is not working.What else I need to include?

Please help..

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: Is it a force close? Then post logcat. Is it working in the way you don't want? Then specify that behavior.

Comment: When I am trying to open the app its showing Unfortunately,HelloWorld_5 has stopped working.

Comment: here nothing happens wrong.
but just as to try 1.)remove the `tools:context="com.example.helloworld_5.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"` this line from xml 2.) change the textview id 3.) no need to declare  `TextView` when you find the text because you declared it globally

Comment: @user3146435 Then please post the error log from logcat. So we can be able to help you better.

Comment: I think you might use the textview t somewhere else than the onCreate(). In onCreate() you have instantiate the local TextView t. So you might get NullPointerException where you used the t outside of the onCreate(). If so, just remove the TextView from the line TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text); below the setContentView.

Answer (score 8):

Change the text attribute of your TextView to id in your xml file...

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
t.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>This is the first line</p>
               <p>This is the second line</p><p>Third line...</p>"));
```

Comment: there is no problem with his/her code at this line but the happen is Forceclose.